# How to increment date format variable?

Tags: php, cakephp-2.5

I need to look up for agreements from '2014-06-01' to $today. I am trying to make loop.

```
 $today=date('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
 $first_day=$my_counter['Counter']['created'];
 $pointer = $first_day;   
        while ($pointer < $today) :
            echo $pointer."<br>";
            $pointer = $pointer + '24:00:00';  // +86400 or +1d not work                
        endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you are using cakephp and you fetch data between '2014-06-01' to $today. If yes then you can use this code.

```
$start = "2014-06-01";
$results = $this->Counter->find('all', array('conditions' => array("created BETWEEN $start AND NOW() ") ));

foreach($results as $value) {

    if( $value['Counter']['age'] != $new_age )
    {
        echo $value['Counter']['created'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make changes according to your requirement try

```
$start = strtotime("2014-07-28 00:00:00");
$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
while($start != $today) {
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
  $start = strtotime('+1 day', $start);
}
```

output :- 2014-07-28 00:00:00  2014-07-29 00:00:00